# Using Mysql Triggers on update/delete/insert

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Ive got a task here to log changes in the database.

So Ive just read about Triggers and that made me interested to try that out.

I got this table in the database were the customer information is described,

(id fornamn, efternam.. etc is the column names and the information underneath is the values)

This table is called "kunder"

```
id  fornamn     efternamn   adress  ort     postnummer  foretag     telefon         email           personNmr   husNmr  organisationsNmr    produkt     uppringd    prioritet   raderad
15  Peter       Tressing    adress  ort     41676       foretag     071234565       email@email.se  123456      4       55658794            Nocria      1           0           0
```

I called this table kunder_log

```
id  fornamn     efternamn   adress  ort     postnummer  foretag     telefon         email           personNmr   husNmr  organisationsNmr    produkt     uppringd    prioritet   raderad     timestamp   type
```

(the only diffirance is index instead of primary key on the ID and I added the timestamp and type)

(Type the type of the query (insert, delete or update))

Now i want to trigger changes for each row in the table when i do an Update/Insert/Delete query.

But I only want to insert the changes made and not every column in the old table.

Is this possible or do you recomend another approache?

Comment: So you are saying you only want the triggers to show the changed columns?

Comment: Ok, because it sounds a bit like you want to **insert** the changes somewhere into another table.

Comment: My main goal is to get the changes made and highlight them in php. So Im not sure if this is the best approach but it seemed like a good one.

Comment: What I meant was that your question is phrased like you want to insert, but actually you want to only log the changed columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two approaches to log all the changes done on main table:

1. trigger is good option if you want to log all the changes made to tables globally.
2. write insert into change log tables after every insert, update, delete statement in all stored procedures.

I generally prefer second approach as it is much faster as compared to triggers.

Sample table structure:

```
kunder
    all_columns

kunder_log
    change_log_id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    all_columns
    change_type ENUM('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE'),
    change_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    change_description VARCHAR(1024)
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid the second option but perhaps I have to go with that one.

Comment: okay then you can go with first approach, as it's easy way to implement it. you just need to write triggers on table for insert, update and delete operations.